# Slider Slideshow Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to made a slideshow that slides left between images. I can get the first image to slide left, but the next image won't show up.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide(); 

        setInterval(function() {
            $('.fadein :first-child').hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 400)
                    .next('img')
                    .show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 400 ).end()
                    .appendTo('.fadein');
        }, 7000);
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fadein">
<img style="width:600px; height:360px" src="images/fourthslide.jpg">
<img style="width:600px; height:360px" src="images/secondslide.jpg">
<img style="width:600px; height:360px" src="images/thirdslide.jpg">
<img style="width:600px; height:360px" src="images/firstslide.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fadein { 
position:relative; 
width:100%;
height:430px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

.fadein img { 
position:absolute; 
vertical-align: middle;
top:10px;
left:0px;
border-top:1px solid navy;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `$('.fadein :first-child')` try `$('.fadein:visible')`

Comment: shoot, that just removes the div region with the images altogether when the first image slides

Comment: can you post your html & css as well?

Comment: and i realize that the html style overrides the css style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is an issue with the jQuery UI. The `.show()` method does not work as expected with the ***slide*** effect if your target element is inline. To demonstrate, I've put together a JSFiddle:

1. Using ***slide***: http://jsfiddle.net/VLqjf/78/
2. Using ***swing***: http://jsfiddle.net/VLqjf/79/

You will notice that if the effect is set to ***swing***, the slideshow works as expected (case 2). However, when it is set to ***slide*** something gets messed up (case 1).

The problem is that the jQuery slide effect wraps your element in a *div.ui_effects_wrapper* that is styled `position:relative`. This breaks the line of images. The basic solution seems to be that you must not position your images inline.

The work-around I tested was to force the *div.ui_effects_wrapper* to be inline, using `.ui-effects-wrapper{display: inline-block !important;}`. Additionally, I animate the width of this div to zero as while it's being slid to the left - this effectively pushes it out of the way so the next img can slide in place. The work-around is in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VLqjf/105/.

Comment: shoot it doesn't work, the first image leaves but the second one doesn't show up

Comment: thanks this helps somewhat, I will see if I can tweak the code. I was looking for only one image showing at a time

Comment: I only had the other images showing so you can see what's happening. All you need to do is change the overflow property of the `.fadein` class to `hidden`, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/VLqjf/107/.